# How can I access Genymotion emulator via IP Address?

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

When I boot my Genymotion emulator it is assigned an ip address - something like `192.168.56.101`.  I install my app on the device and my app starts a small web server on port `8181`.

I used to be able to hit this server via the url: `http://192.168.56.101:8181/` but after upgrades to Genymotion and Virtual Box I can no longer do that.

I can hit the service via a local url (`http://127.0.0.1:8181`) if I use adb port forwarding via the command `adb forward tcp:8181 tcp:8181` so I know the service is working.

How can I configure my networking to make the service accessible via the emulator ip address?

**Update**

When I run an nmap scan against the device I get the following output:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>nmap -vv 192.168.56.101

Starting Nmap 7.12 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2016-08-23 12:50 Eastern Daylight Time
Initiating ARP Ping Scan at 12:50
Scanning 192.168.56.101 [1 port]
Completed ARP Ping Scan at 12:50, 0.50s elapsed (1 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 12:50
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 1 host. at 12:50, 0.02s elapsed
Initiating SYN Stealth Scan at 12:50
Scanning 192.168.56.101 [1000 ports]
Discovered open port 24800/tcp on 192.168.56.101
Discovered open port 5555/tcp on 192.168.56.101
Completed SYN Stealth Scan at 12:50, 1.22s elapsed (1000 total ports)
Nmap scan report for 192.168.56.101
Host is up, received arp-response (0.0020s latency).
Scanned at 2016-08-23 12:50:34 Eastern Daylight Time for 4s
Not shown: 997 closed ports
Reason: 997 resets
PORT      STATE    SERVICE REASON
5555/tcp  open     freeciv syn-ack ttl 64
8181/tcp  filtered unknown no-response
24800/tcp open     unknown syn-ack ttl 64
MAC Address: 08:00:27:DB:D1:0D (Oracle VirtualBox virtual NIC)

Read data files from: C:\Program Files (x86)\Nmap
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 4.62 seconds
           Raw packets sent: 1002 (44.072KB) | Rcvd: 1032 (43.968KB)
```

As you can see port `8181` is showing as filtered.  Was there a firewall of some kind introduced in Android 5.1/6 that would cause this?  I am able to access port `8181` on Android 4.4 emulators but not 5.1/6 emulators.

Comment: Why don't you want to use "adb forward" command? It's really done for what you want to do.

Comment: @eyal-lezmy primarily for reliability on our testing server -> it's problematic when running > 1 emulator to the same ports and adb, when running with > 1 emulator sometimes needs to be killed / restarted which breaks the tunnel

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this issue? I am trying to do a `nmap` scan on the Android AOSP emulator and all the ports show as `open|filtered` to me.